# How to get Entity Framework 4.2 without Nuget?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We need to get hold of Entity Framework 4.2 to test out the SQL generation in 4.2.

Unfortunately, our development environment does not allow us to use Nuget.

Is there any way to get EF4.2 binaries so that we can test it out?

Comment: Just fyi; NuGet doesn't "do" anything if you simply don't use it.

Answer (score 12):

Could you use something like the NuGet Package Explorer (not a part of NuGet)?

http://npe.codeplex.com/

Or, you may be able to download it directly:

http://packages.nuget.org/v1/package/download/entityframework/4.2.0.0

Comment: first download the package explorer then download the package and open it in package explorer, then export..you get the required dlls

Answer (score 3):

If your development environement doesn't allow using NuGet you should probably change it becuase that is the way which MS choose for distributing additional librarires and for exampel EFv4.2 is not distributed in any other form then NuGet. The only option for you is to download it elsewhere and copy EntityFramework.dll to your environement.

Comment: Does this mean I can't isntall EF once for my development environment but need to install it via NuGet Package Manager, for each of my project that want's to use EF?

Comment: @alwayslearning: Generally yes - that is how package repository works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.And how does it work for the design-time tools? How can I get the latest tools?

Comment: @alwayslearning: Design time tools are released as extensions in Visual Studio Gallery.

Comment: You must live in a sheltered world to believe that one can always change their environment. And many great employers have restrictions on such things.

Comment: Unfortunately nuget, created to help with package installation quickly has became a problem by itself. Latest versions of Entity Framework core require updated version of nuget, while it seems so difficult to get a working, updated version of nuget in VS2015 that many of us still use. Knowing how software houses (microsoft in this case) work, to have a fallback strategy is highly advisable, imho.