# ADO.Net entity framework template doesn't exist in my VS10 Ultimate

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-4

ADO.Net Entity Model is not installed or loaded in my VS 10's installed template. Is it something downloadable ? or is it old already, that is why it isnot added in VS10 anymore, if so, could someone let me what replaced it ? 
   Because I just create some tables in the Server Explorer and would like to use them in my ASP.net small project. Sorry my knowledge of this is really limited, i'm glad if someone could help and Please eliminate post rules in the server that limit one IP to have less than 6 posts/day. Thank you.

Comment: Entity data model is an item template and not a project template. If you create a new web project does Entity Data Model not come up as a choice when you select "Add New Item" ?

Comment: Thank you Jeff, as I said, my project now is totally new, I am trying to add a model for it because the database tables are all ready. I need an .edmx to link to ready made tables. Are there other ways around I can do to use them anyway ?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696436/no-entity-data-model-edmx-template-with-visual-studio-2010-sp1-ado-net-entit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26825) and download the latest EF bits (unless you can't move to 4.1 for some reason - if so, find hte version you are using). Then, install. That should expose the templates you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Righ click on your project in solution explorer, then New Item, and then search for ADO.NET Entity Data Model. You will need Entity Framework installed...from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712906) If you don't have [NuGet package managar](http://nuget.org/) install it first, because the newest version of EF is [distributed only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161496/how-to-get-entity-framework-4-2-without-nuget) as a NuGet package.

Comment: You assume the OP has installed NuGet, which is not always the case.